# How can I get this data from database in PHP

Tags: php

I have a multidimentional array which I need to get tyhe documentos data from database, the array is this one:

```
$jayParsedAry = [
        "auth" => [
              "cert" => [
                 "cert-data" => "", 
                 "pkey-data" => "" 
              ] 
           ], 
        "emisor" => "76063822-6", 
        "resolucion" => [
                    "fecha" => "2019-12-23", 
                    "numero" => 0 
                 ], 
        "secuencia" => 1, 
        "documentos" => [
                       [
                          "TpoDoc" => 39, 
                          "NroDoc" => 1, 
                          "TasaImp" => 19, 
                          "FchDoc" => "2020-07-05", 
                          "MntExe" => 0, 
                          "MntNeto" => 100, 
                          "MntIVA" => 19, 
                          "MntTotal" => 119 
                       ], 
                       [
                             "TpoDoc" => 39, 
                             "NroDoc" => 2, 
                             "TasaImp" => 19, 
                             "FchDoc" => "2020-07-05", 
                             "MntExe" => 50, 
                             "MntNeto" => 1000, 
                             "MntIVA" => 190, 
                             "MntTotal" => 1190 
                          ], 
                       [
                                "TpoDoc" => 41, 
                                "NroDoc" => 2, 
                                "TasaImp" => 0, 
                                "FchDoc" => "2020-07-05", 
                                "MntExe" => 100, 
                                "MntNeto" => 0, 
                                "MntIVA" => 0, 
                                "MntTotal" => 100 
                             ] 
                    ] 
     ];
```

I have a:

```
foreach($documentos as $documento) {}
```

I wonder how can I get the documentos part from database? I mean:

foreach($documentos as $documento) {
$jayParsedAry = [][][][][] ??? I do not know how I can get the databa of documentos from database
}

Thanks

Comment: You don't add more data to the array by looping through it. Adding things to an array is well documented in the manual. It's not clear what you mean or how this relates to a database, please provide a clearer and more detailed explanation of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson see the documentos part of the array, you see it has TpoDoc, NroDoc, etc, I need to get that data from database.

Comment: How do we know where and how this data comes from ?  What database tables, what SQL?

Comment: So, do you know how to query a database and get data from it? Have you done that part? It's not clear exactly where you're stuck. At the very least we need to understand the structure the data will be coming from, otherwise we're simply guessing. Once you've extracted the data into some sort of variable, putting it into your existing array is likely to be pretty simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to do this:

```
$jayParsedAry["documentos"][] = [
                                "TpoDoc" => 2, 
                                "NroDoc" => 3, 
                                "TasaImp" => 0, 
                                "FchDoc" => "2021-07-05", 
                                "MntExe" => 100, 
                                "MntNeto" => 0, 
                                "MntIVA" => 0, 
                                "MntTotal" => 100
                               ];
```

Answer (score -1):

$jayParsedAry["documentos"][3] = [obj]